# Como remover do Git um arquivo que era rastreado e agora está no .gitignore?

Tags: git

Tenho um arquivo que era rastreado pelo `git`, porém agora ele está na lista do `.gitignore`.

No entanto, este arquivo continua sendo exibido no `git status` quando é alterado.

**O que fazer para que o `git` esqueça completamente deste arquivo?**

Comment: Quem negativou poderia contribuir indicando o motivo ou respondendo a pergunta?

Answer (score 1):

Se estiverem correctamente na lista do .gitignore,
os seguintes comandos limpam esses ficheiros/directorias.

Por segurança deves confirmar primeiro com a flag -n!!

Limpar ficheiros que não estejam no index / existentes no .gitignore

```
git clean -n -xf

Se correcto então:

git clean -xf
```

Eliminar pastas que não estejam no index / existentes no .gitignore

```
git clean -n -df

Se correcto então:

git clean -df
```

Comment: Isso remove remotamente também?

Comment: @PedroFerreira, o `-n` é o _dry run_?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado desculpa a demora mas sim, como esta referido, por segurança com -n para fazer um dry run/obter uma análise do que vai ser removido

Comment: @PedroFerreira, tendo a informação eu fico feliz, por mais que ela demore